# How to make a color brighter

Tags: android, colors

I have a color that I get in runtime. I need to find a way to make it a bit brighter. I found a few examples on line, none worked for me.

The only thing that made any difference to the color was changing to HSV. But I couldn't understand how it worked.

Comment: What did you find? What did you try? What happened? Did the colour change at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RGB values manually:

```
final int brighter = 25;
Color.rgb(Color.red(color) + brighter, Color.green(color) + brighter, Color.blue(color) + brighter);
```

You of course would have to make something that checks that any value does not get over 255.

**EDIT** [Palette](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/graphics/Palette.html) won't work with a single color.

Comment: Isn't the pallet extracting colors from the Bitmap? and it will only give me the same color... isn't it?

Comment: Indeed it is. You said you already got a color. That `Bitmap` there is just used for `Palette`. `Palette` gives you easy alternative colors without the need to decompose it's (A)RGB values. Otherwise you could always add a given amount to RGB values. See edit.

Comment: As far as I understand the pallet is not giving alternatives... It's extracting colors... So if you will give it only blue it will only extract blue. If you give it an image with a lot of colors it will than give you a vibrant color from that image. Is it not?

Comment: Hm... yes you're right (my bad). If your color is all the same indeed I was mistaken and Palette won't do a thing. You'll have to manually edit RGB values. See edit.